# Converting ESRI File Geodatabase (FileGDB) to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, convert, file-geodatabase, error, drivers

I am trying to convert ESRI FileGDB to PostGIS

- I created a new database: 'newkelibia' with pgAdmin 4
- using OSGeo4W shell I executed this:

  ```
   ogr2ogr, -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='1234' dbname='newkelibia'" C:\Users\ons\Documents\CityEngine\Default Workspace\new_project\models\KlibiaBD.gdb" -overwrite -progress --config PG_USE_COPY YES
  ```

and I got this error:

> ERROR 1: PostgreSQL driver doesn't currently support database
> creation. Please create database with the `createdb' command. ERROR 1:
> PostgreSQL driver failed to create

Did I mess any steps ?

Comment: did you add the postgis extension to the database?

Comment: Have you tried without the single quotes in `dbname='newkelibia'`

Comment: Do I count wrong or is there one closing " missing? And test the connection first with `ogrinfo PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='1234' dbname='newkelibia'"`.

Comment: @lan Turton yes

Comment: @user30184 I add the missing , and I tested the connection now : ogrinfo PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='1234' dbname='newkelibia'"
INFO: Open of `PG:host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='1234' dbname='newkelibia''
using driver `PostgreSQL' successful.
AND I GOT THE SAME MSG

Comment: Then check that PostGIS is OK with `ogrinfo PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user='postgres' password='1234' dbname='newkelibia'" -sql "select postgis_version()"`.

Comment: @user30184 I think its ok

Comment: Do you really have `ogr2ogr,` in your command line, with comma?

Answer (score 1):

Running ogr2ogr so that the program name is followed by a comma "," gives rather similar error message for me on Windows.

```
ogr2ogr, -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 user='user' password='password' dbname='test'" -overwrite test.gpkg --config PG_USE_COPY YES
ERROR 1: PostgreSQL driver doesn't currently support database creation.
Please create database with the `createdb' command.
ERROR 1: PostgreSQL driver failed to create ,
```

Syntax `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" ...` works fine.

I am not sure if this is some sort of bug. It seems that comma can follow the native Windows commands and then it means a separator between the command and the first parameter.
So this `dir,/s,c:\temp` does the same job than `dir /s c:\temp`.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47222968/what-does-the-comma-after-a-command-do. Anyway, commas do not work as parameter separators for gdal command line utilities. Use spaces.

Comment: thank you @user30184 I have no more error message or any message, what does this mean ?

Comment: Hopefully success. Have a look at your database.

Comment: unfortunately , nothing has changed :(